# ¿Cuál es el gentilicio de las personas de Alaska?

Tags: vocabulario, adjetivos, gentilicio

¿Cuál es el gentilicio correcto para hacer referencia a las personas que viven en Alaska?

Comment: ¿sera samoyedo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La RAE indica [*alasqueño/a*](http://dle.rae.es/alasque%C3%B1o) o [*alaskeño/a*](http://dle.rae.es/alaske%C3%B1o).

Otras propuestas como *alaskano*, *alaskiano*, *alaskense*, *alascense* se pueden encontrar [aquí](http://translationjournal.net/journal//30gentilicios.htm), pero no son reconocidas por la RAE.